# Analytical Solution vs NDSolve. How to find agreement?

Tags: differential-equations

I have an ODE to which I know the solution. When using NDSolve to find the same solution, the result doesn't agree with the analytical solution.

I am looking for advice on what I could try modifying within the code so that the numeric solution agrees with the analytical solution. Thank you!

The code is below:

```
(*Defining functions and constants*)
P[r_, z_] := (2. r ((2 - (4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + 
             z^2)) EllipticK[(4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)] - 
       2 EllipticE[(4 r)/((1 + r)^2 + z^2)]))/(\[Pi] ((4 r)/((1 + 
            r)^2 + z^2)) \[Sqrt]((1 + r)^2 + z^2));
Zmaxreg = 15;
Zminreg = -Zmaxreg;
Rmaxreg = 54;
Rminreg = 0;
PRef = 1;
a = 4;
zH2 = 100000; 
r = 0.1;

(*Numeric Solution*)
solnum = 
  NDSolve[
   {nH2'[z] == -zH2*nH2[z]*(P[r, z]/PRef)^a,
    nH2[Zminreg] == 1},
   (*VARIABLES TO SOLVE FOR*)
   {nH2},
   (*RANGE TO SOLVE OVER*)
   {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg}];

(*Analytic Solution*)
rstable = Table[rj, {rj, r, r, r}];
zstable = Table[zj, {zj, -100, 50, 10}]; 
IsTable = 
  Table[0, {j, 1, Dimensions[rstable][[1]]}, {k, 1, 
    Dimensions[zstable][[1]]}];

Do[Do[IsTable[[j, k]] = 
   IsTable[[j, k - 1]] + 
    P[rstable[[j]] + 0.0001, zstable[[k]]]^
     a (zstable[[k]] - zstable[[k - 1]])/PRef^a,
  {k, 2, Dimensions[zstable][[1]]}], {j, 1, Dimensions[rstable][[1]]}]

IsFunTable = 
  Table[{rstable[[j]], zstable[[k]], IsTable[[j, k]]}, {j, 1, 
    Dimensions[rstable][[1]]}, {k, 1, Dimensions[zstable][[1]]}]; 
IsFun = Interpolation[Flatten[IsFunTable, 1]];
solexact[z_] := Exp[-zH2 IsFun[r, z]];

(*Plotting*)
Plot[{nH2[z] /. solnum[[1]], solexact[z]}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"Numeric", "Analytic"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "nH2"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: Well, this is curious: `Plot[{-nH2'[z]/10^5 /. solnum[[1]], solexact[z]}, {z, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], AbsoluteThickness[2]}]`

Comment: And `-1/10^5` cancels the factor `-zH2` in the ode...(?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! I found an error in the form of the solution I had in the code. The agreement is much better now. I think there might still be some errors as I continue to develop this based on past work, but for now, this was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: @Bill How do you come up with the exact solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Extended comment/perhaps an answer**

`Separation of variables` shows

```
n'[z]/n[z] == f[z] /.n -> Function[z, /[Integrate[f[u], {u,Zminreg, z}]]] (* True *)
n[Zminreg] /. n -> Function[z, Exp[Integrate[f[u], {u,Zminreg, z}]]]  (* True *)
```

that the general solution of the ode-problem is

```
Log[nH2[z]]== Integrate[-zH2 *(P[r, zz ]/PRef)^a, {zz ,Zminreg, z}]
```

Unfortunately Mathematica isn't able to solve the right handside.

Trying numerical approximation of the integral

```
int[u_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z,Zminreg,u}]
```

results in unexpected behavior, if we compare integrand(blue) and integral(red):

```
Plot[{-zH2 *(P[r, z]/PRef)^a, int[z]} // Evaluate, {z,Zminreg,Zmaxreg}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Obviously this result is useless as numerical approximation of the general solution, because integral should give a stepwise function (not a peak)!

**addendum**

Because integrand vanishs in a wide range it helps NIntegrate if we split the integration range accordingly:

```
int =.
int[u_?NumericQ] := 
 Which[u < -1, 
  NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z , Zminreg, u}  ], u < 1, 
  NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z , Zminreg, -1}  ] + 
   NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z , -1, u}  ], u > 1,
  NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z , Zminreg, -1}  ] + 
   NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z , -1, 1}  ] + 
   NIntegrate[-zH2 *(P[r, z ]/PRef)^a, {z , 1, u}  ]]  

Plot[{-zH2 *(P[r, z]/PRef)^a, int[z]} // Evaluate, {z, Zminreg, Zmaxreg}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}] // Quiet
```

[image]

shows much better result. Agreement with `solnum`

```
Plot[{nH2[z] /. solnum[[1]], Exp[int[z]]}, {z, Zminreg,Zmaxreg}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

is very well.